# play private playlist with youtube player api on android

Tags: android, android-youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I can get user's playlist ids on youtube with youtube data api v3. Also, I can play playlists that are public but not the private ones with youtube player api.

Youtube player api is not a must for me, I can switch to any other thing you can offer. All I want is to play the private playlists.

Although my app is authenticated by user (as I said, I already have access to user's info), I get an error: (from logcat)

```
09-11 18:21:05.774: E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI(21823): apps.youtube.datalib.common.b.n.a:36 Http error: status=[403] msg=[Forbidden, GData error(s):
09-11 18:21:05.774: E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI(21823):   [{domain:GData,code:ServiceForbiddenException,location:null,internalReason:User authentication required.}]]
```

I think the problem is related to the youtube player api, it doesn't have this functionality, I must somehow edit youtube player api to support play private playlists.

This is the screenshot of the error I get:
http://s17.postimg.org/8vjvnd00f/Screenshot_2014_09_11_18_21_41.png

and these is my code related to the question: (I have a single activty which is the main activity)

```
public static final String DEVELOPER_YTDATA_KEY="my key from google developer console";
public static final String TAG="bestsongs";

private Context context;

private final HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
private final JsonFactory jsonFactory = new GsonFactory();

/**
 * Define a global instance of a Youtube object, which will be used
 * to make YouTube Data API requests.
 */
private static YouTube youtube;

private static final int REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER = 2;
private static final int REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION = 3;

private String mChosenAccountName;

public static final String ACCOUNT_KEY = "accountName";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    context=this;   

    chooseAccount();
}


public class GetPlaylist extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

    /**
     * Initialize a YouTube object to search for videos on YouTube. Then
     * display the name and thumbnail image of each video in the result set.
     *
     * @param args command line args.
     */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {         

        String playlistID=null;
        try {       

            String authToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context,
                    mChosenAccountName, "oauth2:" + YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE);

            GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential();

            credential.setAccessToken(authToken);


            // This object is used to make YouTube Data API requests.
            YouTube youtube = new YouTube.Builder(transport, jsonFactory,
                    credential).setApplicationName(Constants.APP_NAME)
                    .build();

            Log.d(TAG, "a");

            // Define the API request for retrieving search results.
            PlaylistListResponse ytPlaylistResponse = youtube.playlists()
                    .list("id,snippet")
                    .setMine(true)
                    .execute();

            //Iterate over results
            List<Playlist> playlistResultList = ytPlaylistResponse.getItems();
            if(playlistResultList!=null){
                //for(int i=0; i<playlistResultList.size(); i++){
                playlistID=playlistResultList.get(1).getId();
                Log.d(TAG, "playlist id: "+playlistID);
                //}
            }

        } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,"There was a service error: " + e.getDetails().getCode() + " : "
                    + e.getDetails().getMessage());
        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
            // User needs to authorize this application, or take some other action
            Intent authIntent = e.getIntent();
            startActivityForResult(authIntent, REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
            Log.e(TAG,"UserRecoverableAuthException: " + e.getCause() + " : " + e.getMessage() +" : "+ e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,"GoogleAuthException: " + e.getCause() + " : " + e.getMessage() +" : "+ e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,"Playlist IOException: " + e.getCause() + " : " + e.getMessage() +" : "+ e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return playlistID; 

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String playlistID){
        if(YouTubeIntents.isYouTubeInstalled(context)) {
            if(YouTubeApiServiceUtil.isYouTubeApiServiceAvailable(context)
                    == YouTubeInitializationResult.SUCCESS) {
                // start the YouTube player
                startActivity(
                        YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createPlaylistIntent(
                                (Activity) context, DEVELOPER_YTDATA_KEY, playlistID));
            }
        }
    }
}


private void chooseAccount() {
    Log.d(TAG, "in choose account");
    Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null, new String[]{"com.google"},
             false, null, null, null, null);
    startActivityForResult(intent,
            REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION:
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            chooseAccount();
            Log.d(TAG, "in onresult request_auth");
        }
        break;
    case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null
        && data.getExtras() != null) {
            String accountName = data.getExtras().getString(
                    AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
            if (accountName != null) {
                mChosenAccountName = accountName;
                Log.d(TAG, "accountName onresult: "+mChosenAccountName);
                new GetPlaylist().execute();
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

I have already tried GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2 authentication as well, exactly the same problem. (I mean the method here https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-android/blob/master/src/com/google/ytdl/MainActivity.java)

Comment: did you solve the problem? I've the same issue also

Comment: No, you cannot get private ones :(